# Where is Eclipse Maven project Archtype information saved

Tags: java, maven, pom.xml, maven-archetype

I am using Eclipse Juno with the latest Maven plugin.
I use the New project Wizard, and create a new Maven project using the archetype X.
Eclipse and Maven do their business and create the project and everything is awesome.

A few days later, i am creating a new project, and i would like to use the same archetype X, however i don't remember the name of this archetype.

My only hope is to find out what archetype i used for my earlier project. But i cannot locate any config file in that project that hold the archetype information (not even the POM file).

So, my question - given a Maven project, how do i find out what archetype was used to create that project?

Comment: I think there is no way to discover that. Maybe You can deliver your pom and write what your project can do. And we will find an appropriate one.

Comment: in this case, i knew what my archetype was. but i was wondering if i had forgotten my archetype, where would i recover that information from. the fact that i cannot find archetype info in pom or other settings file is very bothersome to me, and is indicative of losing some meta-information/traceability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As of today, i have found no discernible way to determine the Archetype of a project from the information contained in its POM file. The only way to do this is to compare your POM to that of of archtypes in Maven repository till you find a match (very subjective and indeterministic).
All this applies to my experience with Eclipse projects created using Maven plugin.